# Installing Ensime for Scala Development on emacs: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ensime#ensime-sbtt-cmd;0.12: not found

Tags: scala, emacs, sbt, ensime

I have placed the line:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbtt-cmd" % "0.12")
```

into my `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt`

But, when I try to run `sbt` within the root directory of my project, I get:

```
Loading /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/djg/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/home/djg/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.ensime#ensime-sbtt-cmd;0.12 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.ensime#ensime-sbtt-cmd;0.12
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.ensime/ensime-sbtt-cmd/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.12/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.ensime/ensime-sbtt-cmd/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.12/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/djg/.ivy2/local/org.ensime/ensime-sbtt-cmd/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.12/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ensime/ensime-sbtt-cmd_2.10_0.13/0.12/ensime-sbtt-cmd-0.12.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.ensime#ensime-sbtt-cmd;0.12: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      org.ensime:ensime-sbtt-cmd:0.12 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn] 
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ensime#ensime-sbtt-cmd;0.12: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1144)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1142)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1165)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1163)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1167)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1162)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1170)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1135)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1113)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ensime#ensime-sbtt-cmd;0.12: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I was guessing the VERSION number was wrong, so I tried replacing `"0.12"` with `"0.13"`, and `"0.12-SNAPSHOT"`, but keep getting similar results.

My goal is to use `ensime` with `emacs` to edit Scala code. What am I missing?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226714/sbt-cannot-resolve-ensime-sbt-cmd-in-a-play2-scala-project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [build file of that plugin](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime-sbt-cmd/blob/master/build.sbt#L7):

```
version := "0.1.2"
```

the correct version seems to be `"0.1.2"`, not `"0.12"`. (see [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/ensime/ensime-sbt-cmd_2.10_0.13/0.1.2/)).

Furthermore, you have a typo in the arifact name: It's `"ensime-sbt-cmd"` not `"ensime-sbtt-cmd"`.

---

Normally, sbt should find stuff in oss.sonatype.org even if it doesn't get through to Maven Central. However, I'm not sure this goes for plugins as well, therefore you might try to explicitly add a resolver for it:

```
resolvers += 
  "Sonatype releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting the same problem with "0.1.2" as with "0.12"

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Thanks! :) Also, please add the part about the typo to your answer. The combination of that and changing the version to "0.1.2" is what did the trick.

Comment: I also get this exception, after I've made the changes recommended: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ensime#ensime-sbt-cmd;0.1.2: not found.  Any thoughts?